# Create a project from command line

Tags: python, django, deployment, sentry

[Sentry](https://www.getsentry.com/) catches loggings and errors from client applications.

The only way I know of creating a project in Sentry is by manually submitting the form in the Web application interface.

I'm searching for a way to create a project into Sentry from the command line in any way (options, config file) ?

This would be greatly valuable for deployment scripts. Otherwise no automation is possible.

Just found this discussion while Googling around but no answer:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/getsentry/pWglAEHaPUk/discussion

Any idea?

Comment: I think this is probably too specific ... not many will even know what sentry is.... you may want to provide a link to getsentry.com at the very least and probably describe how one normally adds a project to sentry if there is a way to do it in the python shell or only on their admin page or what..

Comment: Well, this is a valuable comment. Question edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [a django project](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/blob/master/src/sentry/models.py#L107), of course you can:

```
from sentry.models import Project
project = Project(...)
...
project.save()
```

**Edit:** You could [write a custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) to get functionality on the command line

**Edit by question's author**: Yes indeed it is a django project, so like a django project I automated my deployment in the three following steps:

1. Start Sentry, create users, teams and projects and adjust settings from the admin Web interface
2. Run dumpdata like you'd do with any django project (sentry will implicitly call manage.py):

   `sentry --config=sentry.conf.py dumpdata --indent=2 auth > auth_data.json`

   `sentry --config=sentry.conf.py dumpdata --indent=2 sentry > sentry_data.json`
3. Deploy step by step:

   `sentry --config=sentry.conf.py syncdb --noinput`

   `sentry --config=sentry.conf.py migrate`

   `sentry --config=sentry.conf.py loaddata auth_data.json`

   `sentry --config=sentry.conf.py loaddata sentry_data.json`

Works pretty well. Hope this will help others.

Comment: Well that was the Plan B. Plan A was to see if the command line tool has some more options, maybe undocumented. I'll try that tomorrow, many thanks.

Comment: Edited the question with my complements and accepting the answer. Thanks @Timmy.

Comment: The dumpdata -> loaddata method seems questionable to me.  The first thought that comes to mind is that you are then using the same public/private key combos across different deployments.

Answer (score 1):

As officially stated in [Sentry's docs](https://docs.getsentry.com/on-premise/server/faq/):

```
# Bootstrap the Sentry environment
from sentry.utils.runner import configure
configure()

# Do something crazy
from sentry.models import Team, Project, User

user = User()
user.username = 'admin'
user.email = 'admin@localhost'
user.is_superuser = True
user.set_password('admin')
user.save()

team = Team()
team.name = 'Sentry'
team.owner = user
team.save()

project = Project()
project.team = team
project.owner = user
project.name = 'Default'
project.save()

key = ProjectKey.objects.filter(project=project)[0]
print 'SENTRY_DSN = "%s"' % (key.get_dsn(),)
```

https://docs.getsentry.com/on-premise/server/faq/

Comment: configure() uses the default sentry conf file. How to specify /home/me/path/to/my/project/sentry.conf.py ??

Comment: A quick look at the [code of the configure() method](http://git.io/iwEtlw) suggests to call logan.runner.configure_app instead. Another solution would be to stick with configure() and creating a symlink ~/.sentry/sentry.conf.py -> /path/to/sentry.conf.py

Comment: looks like the link has changed to: https://docs.getsentry.com/on-premise/server/faq/

Comment: @abhishekmukherg thanks for that, I've edited my answer